# How to show personal certificates in JSF?

Tags: jsf, openssl, x509certificate

I'm developing a JSF application with Eclipse, JSF 2, Tomcat 7 and Primefaces 5. I've achieved to establish a SSL connection (https) with OpenSsl.

I'd like my application to press a button in the login form, and show the list of personal X509 certificates which are in the browser's store. Many webs implement this functionality, so I realize that this is possible, and without using applets.

Is this so hard? I'm looking for examples but I can't find anything.

Comment: Are you asking about the native certificate list which is show by the browser or SO when you want to authenticate with your client to the server in order to log in (two way SSL)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want to get the list that the browser (IE) show in:  INTERNET OPTIONS --> CONTENT TAB --> CERTIFICATES --> PERSONAL TAB

Comment: yes I suppose  you were talking about the SO certificate or browser (Firefox) certificate list, however I was asking about the intention. If you want to show it for the client authentication (this is easy because is native supported by the browsers) or it's for another purpose, if this is the case I think that your only way is to use an  extension like java applet to work with all browsers or another "plugin" way like for IE activeXObject...

Comment: I want to show the list for client authentication. I'd like the user to log in via user-name/password or choosing a certificate from a list (Many webs implement this, for example I log  in my university web by this way)

Comment: The only thing to do is configure your webserver. The most easy way to enable ssl client authentication for you webapp running in tomcat IMO is behind a webserver like http://httpd.apache.org/. However if you want to config tomcat with openssl you can use the ARP implementation, take a look on http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html and specially in this section http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File

Comment: albciff, I did this example step by step [link](http://virgo47.wordpress.com/2010/08/23/tomcat-web-application-with-ssl-client-certificates/) and it worked, but this isn't what I want. When I access https://localhost:8443/myapp the bwrowser shows a certificate , but (1) Only show the certificate I created in the example (2) this happens everytime I access my application, and I only wish that this happens when I press a button. I think this is too difficult for me, and it's only for security Java experts. Thanks, however

Comment: I make an answer trying to guide you in your remaining problems, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in your comments you follow this [tutorial](http://virgo47.wordpress.com/2010/08/23/tomcat-web-application-with-ssl-client-certificates/) and you can configure your tomcat to use two way ssl, now you have the next problems for which I try to give you some guide lines:

> **(1) Only show the certificate I created in the example**

The problem is probably that your browser is only showing the certificate which are issued by the self-signed CA loaded in your server trust store. This is you have in your `server.xml` your tomcat `<Connector>` like:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
truststoreFile=".../cacerts.jks" truststorePass="changeit"
keystoreFile="..../keystore.jks" keystorePass="changeit"
clientAuth="true" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

So if you want that the browser show all client certificates issued by a specific CA like for example verisign (may be in your case dnie, fnmt?) you have to add the issuer CA certificate (and the intermediate certificates if necessary) in `cacerts.jks`. You can do it with java `keytool` (you can found it in `JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool`):

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias yourCaAlias -file CA_certificate.crt -keystore cacerts.jks
```

> **(2) this happens everytime I access my application, and I only wish that this happens when I press a button.**

This can be do it in different ways, a simple approach for example is configure two connectors in your tomcat `server.xml` file; one for your public access through http and another one for private access with https. In the public part you could have the log in page with your log in button and some stuff, when user click on log in button the webapp can redirect to the connector where you've configured your client authentication (https://yourserver.com/blabla...) so the browser prompt the user to select a valid certificate to authenticate, then in your webapp you could have configured one servlet which can perform the certificate validation and the required things for your webapp like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.security.cert.X509Certificate;

// Extend HttpServlet class
public class ServletCertificateSample extends HttpServlet {
    private String message;

    public void init() throws ServletException {
        // Do required initialization
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    private X509Certificate getCertificate(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException
            X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
            if (null != certs && certs.length > 0) {
                // cert found
                // performs certificate operations...
            }
            throw new ServletException("No client certificate found");
    }

    public void destroy() {
        // do nothing.
    }
}
```

I hope that this puts you on the right direction,

Comment: Life becomes nicer because of people who help for free, like you. I'm sorry because I'm not ranked and I can't vote you up. Now I can see my "fnmt" certificates! I have to implement the second part (redirect when the button is pressed) but I'm sure it's going to work. Can I help you anyway? If you come from Barcelona to Plasencia you'll get a free beer!

Comment: jajaj it's so far for a free beer, thanks anyways `:)`.However my girlfriend parents are from navas del madroño so may be on holidays...

Comment: I finally achieved it! Redirecting, as you said, but no without problems. I did it redirecting from http:localhost:8080/myapp to https:localhost:8443/myapp (here the browser shows the certificates). In the welcome file with <f:event> I can see if the request have an X509 certificate and I can render the forms that I want depending on it. It works fine.